# How can I get the caller from an incoming phone call webhook request?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm going to develop a webhook for incoming calls in Twilio:

```
app.post('/voice', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
  const caller = ...;
  twiml.say('hello, your number is ' + caller);
  res.type('text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

How can I get the caller phone number from the request (`req`)? I don't need the name, but just the number.

I can't find in docs what is sent in the POST body when a webhook is invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `caller phone number` you're looking for is in `req` object.

It's `req.body.From`.

In your example `const caller = ...;`

becomes `const caller = req.body.From;`.

---

***Docs:***

- Request parameters
  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters
- Respond to incoming phone calls in Node.js
  https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-in-node-js#write-nodejs-code-to-handle-the-incoming-phone-call
- Call Monitoring with Node.js
  https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/monitoring-call-progress-events-with-node-js-and-express.html